# little oh notation as the limit of n goes to infinity

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm just trying to understand how in little o notation this is true:

**f(n)/g(n) as n goes to infinity = 0**?

Can someone explain that to me?

I do get the idea that f(n) = o(g(n)) means that f(n) grows no faster then cg(n) for all constants c > 0.

I just don't get the bit in bold above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_o_notation#Little-o_notation

You've left something out, namely your definitions for `f` and `g`.

It would appear that the precondition for the bolded statement is `g(n) in o(f(n))`.

According to the Wikipedia article, `f(n) = o(g(n))` means that `f` grows *slower* than `cg(n)` for all positive constants. So `f(n)` is not in `o(f(n))`.

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb, but not sure what that means:  "So f(n) is not in o(f(n))."  Can you put that in more plain english?

Comment: `o(f(n))` is a class of functions. A function is either in the class or it's not. `f(n)` is not, despite being part of the definition of that class.

Comment: so f(n) is not in o(f(n)) because f(n) cannot grow slower then itself.  Would I be correct in my statement?

Answer (score 0):

There was a great episode of BBC's Horizon (titled '[To Infinity and Beyond](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00qszch)') recently that explained this.

Comment: Darn looks like it's not on iPlayer anymore. Keep an eye out for a repeat - it was cool.